# Preg_Match For YouTube Views

Tags: php, youtube, view, preg-match

**I'm new to php and i'm facing this problem. Need some help in matching the youtube views preg_match.
The below codes posted are the codes i made for the preg match but these are not working. Can anyone help me out.**

```
      if($row['type']=="Views"){
      $data = $row['data'];
      $type = "YouTube Views";
      //INSTAGRAM
$file = @file_get_contents($data);
preg_match('/\"watch-view-count":(.*?)\,/',$file,$mfc);  
$ccnt = $mfc[1];
//INSTAGRAM
      }
       if($row['type']=="Views"){
      $data = $row['data'];
       $type = "YouTube Views";
           //Views
$file = @file_get_contents($data) or die("YouTube Offline ? :/");
preg_match('/\"watch-view-count":(.*?)\,/',$file,$mfc);               
$ccnt = $mfc[1];
```

**$data = http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPmhFrwDJTo
I need the preg_match to get the current count of views in the youtube video. I'm really sorry for the bad grammar.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1438393) use regex for parsing HTML. Use a [DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead. It'll be more efficient.

In this case, you can simple use the Youtube API:

```
<?php
$video_ID = 'BPmhFrwDJTo';
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$video_ID}?v=2&alt=json");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
$views = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
echo $views.' views';
?>
```

Output:

```
7 views
```

Comment: I'm sorry mate i'm new to php and still i tried this. I dont understand what actually you are trying to say ??

Comment: @Exceptional: I've added an example. Hope that helps!